# Spells that are based on Windwalk

Tags: dota-2, dota

Since you can use any spell based on windwalk while tping without interrupting it i would like to know which spells are based on windwalk.

The ones i know are windrun, clinkz's invis, ghost walk, vendetta.

I am sure i am missing some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are currently 10 abilities concidered as windwalking abilities :

**Skills :**

- Shadow Walk (Gondar)
- Wind Walk (Brewmaster Storm Brewling)
- Skeleton Walk (Clinkz)
- Ghost Walk (Invoker)
- Vendetta (Nyx assassin)
- Shukuchi (Weaver)

**Items :**

- Shadow Amulet's Fade
- Shadow Blade's Shadow Walk
- Phase Boots' Phase
- Glimmer cape

Some other spells that are not based on windwalk can be casted without interrputing chanelling aswell (such as [Whirling Death](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Timbersaw#Whirling_death)). Also this does not apply only to Teleport Scroll but to any channeling spells. That's why you can often witness Witch Doctors buy a Shadow Blade and use it during Death Ward's channel.

Comment: oh well. i wonder why i never see weavers and pls abusing this fact. even better escapes! i should consider buying shadow amulet more often now.

Comment: @Wandang Especially since fade time went down. As a weaver player I use it as an offsenive mechanism and Shukuchi while I'm TPing to a tower to defend it so I arrive invis and untargettable. Very usefull. Same trick With Shadow blade, most of the time the hero will think you cancelled your tp at the last second while in fact you are waiting to backstab them

Comment: Nice! never thought about that one. Until now i only started alch's stun b4 tping to maximize it at arrival. Your strat will open a whole bunch of new possibilities

Comment: @WizLiz windrun isn't based on WW in Dota 2 right ? You didn't list it, but I want to be sure

Comment: @T_O I don't think it is and after checking the wiki it's not listed as. Plus the ability windrun on the wiki doesn't mention "does not interrupt channeling" when it's mentionned on Whirling Death.

Comment: Phase boots are actually coded as a Windwalk as well, just with an unreachable fade time. This is why most actions cancel their effect.